# SOAP error: failed to load external entity

Tags: php, magento, soap

I am using soup and following code:

```
try{
    $opts = array(
        'http' => array(
            'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $wsdlUrl = 'https://someurl.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl';

    $soapClientOptions = array(
        'stream_context' => $context,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    );

    $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, $soapClientOptions);
    $sessionId = $soapClient->login('test', 'pass123'); 

    print_r($sessionId);exit;


}
catch(SoapFault $ex){
    print_r($ex->getMessage());
}
catch(Exception $ex) {
    print_r($ex->getMessage());
}
```

I am getting soupClient response perfectly. But error arise when I trying to login.

Error is:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://someurl.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity "https://someurl.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1"
```

**N.B php version is 7.0 & magento 1.9.4.0**

Looking for a solution.

Comment: are you trying to use one of the magento ver 1 apis?

Comment: Yes it is magento 1.9.4.0 and soap_v2 @Rakesh KumarJakhar

Comment: Please follow this tutorial to get it working 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html